# Bluetooth Pairing - AuthenticationCanceled

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I'm trying to pair my *Ubuntu 20.04* laptop with a **Logitech MX Keys Mini** keyboard.

My bluetooth can find the device, but I am getting an error when I try to pair with it:

```
[bluetooth]# pair <MAC Address>
[bluetooth]# Attempting to pair with <MAC Address>
[bluetooth]# Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Other times, I get this error:

```
[bluetooth]# pair <MAC Address>
Attempting to pair with <MAC Address>
[CHG] Device <MAC Address> Connected: yes
[agent] Passkey: 299595
[CHG] Device <MAC Address> Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

I have been able to pair with other devices, so I don't think there is any problem with my bluetooth. However, these devices required a passkey to connect, whereas this keyboard I believe should pair automatically, as there is no interface for inputting a passkey.

So the bluetooth seems to be able to discover the keyboard without issue, but I don't know how to go about pairing with it.

Has anyone else ran in to the same issue with pairing a keyboard on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to **enter the passkey on the keyboard itself** and press enter and it worked.